# Error status cannot be calculated for start_date with no apparent reason

Tags: civimember

[Similar to this thread](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6381/when-importing-memberships-into-4-6-8-what-does-the-membership-cannot-be-save?rq=1), I'm suddenly unable to import memberships due to "status cannot be calculated for start_date" -- the first import worked fine, but despite using the same membership type and start date that were used in the first import, the second import keeps throwing "status cannot be calculated for start_date" on every record. I've tried editing the Membership Status Rules, then later disabling them. Nothing has worked so far. Is this a bug?

CiviCRM 5.52.0 | WordPress 6.02

Answer (score 1):

I just updated CiviCRM, and the problem appears to have been fixed. The only change I made was updating to 5.53.0, and right after I did so, my second membership import finally succeeded.

Comment: Good to hear it is fixed now.  If you get this in the future, provide a screenshot of your status rules.